# Dependent/Chained Drop down List is not working in modal

Tags: django, ajax, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to use dependant/chained  dropdown list in Django with the help of ajax (https://cutt.ly/MyVQE74) like if i select a company then only then that company department will show up in the modal. it worked in main page for the search function but not working in the modal part while posting data.

## model_part

```
class Item(models.Model):

    item_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank =True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    department = models.ForeignKey(Department, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    employee = models.ForeignKey(Employee, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
```

## view_part

```
def save_item_form(request, form, template_name):

    data = dict()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            data['form_is_valid'] = True
            items = Item.objects.all()
            data['html_item_list'] = render_to_string('item/includes/partial_item_list.html', {
                'items': items
            })
        else:
            data['form_is_valid'] = False
    context = {'form': form}
    data['html_form'] = render_to_string(
        template_name, context, request=request)
    return JsonResponse(data)


def item_create(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ItemForm(request.POST)
    else:
        form = ItemForm()
    return save_item_form(request, form, 'item/includes/partial_item_create.html')

def load_department(request):

    company_id = request.GET.get('company')
    departments= Department.objects.filter(company_id=company_id).order_by('name')
    context={'departments':departments}
    return render(request,'item/department_drop_down.html',context)



def load_employees(request):
    department_id =request.GET.get('department')
    employees = Employee.objects.filter(department_id=department_id).order_by('name')
    context={'employees':employees}
    return render(request,'item/employee_drop_down.html',context)
```

## Templates view (using modal):

## name: partial_create_form.html

```
<form method="post" action="{% url 'item_create' %}" class="js-item-create-form" id="itemForm" data-departments-url="{% url 'ajax_load_departments'%}" data-employees-url="{% url 'ajax_load_employees'%}" >
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Create a new Item</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        {% include 'item/includes/partial_item_form.html' %}
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Create Item</button>
    </div>
</form>

<script>

    $(document).on('click', '#id_company', function() {
        var url = $("#itemForm").attr("data-departments-url");
        var companyId = $(this).val();
        console.log(companyId)
        $.ajax({
    url: url,
            data: {
    'company': companyId
            },
            success: function(data) {
    $("#id_department").html(data);
            }
        });

    });

$(document).on('click', '#id_department', function() {
    var url = $("#itemForm").attr("data-employees-url");
    var departmentId = $(this).val();
    console.log(departmentId)
    $.ajax({
url: url,
        data: {
'department': departmentId
        },
        success: function(data) {
$("#id_employee").html(data);
        }
    });

});

</script>
```

## ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

## name: partial_item_form.html

```
{% for field in form %}
    <div class="form-group{% if field.errors %} has-error{% endif %}">

        <label for="{{ field.id_for_label }}">{{ field.label }}</label>
        {% render_field field class="form-control" %}
        {% for error in field.errors %}
            <p class="help-block">{{ error }}</p>
        {% endfor %}

    </div>

{% endfor %}
```